# Multiple Echos organized by Alexa for Business and filtered by DSN?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-for-business

Context: I am deploying multiple Amazon Echos at a single location in different rooms. These echos are managed in Alexa For Business. These echos will share many parts of the same skill, but in our AWS Lambda function, several environment variables should be segregated between these. In particular, we inform the Echo users what the wifi code is for their room, which will vary between rooms (and which other rooms should not be able to access.)

What I'd like to do is have those environment variables filter by the Echos' DSNs. Is this possible?

Or is this better to do at the skill level? We considered that, but we're not sure how to get around the inability to use similar invocation names and we do want to use consistent invocation names due to simplicity in user training.

More info: Using Node.js 6.10 and a template based on this: https://github.com/Donohue/alexa

I am not a smart man. Please feel free to hand-hold me in your answers. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The context object holds a field named `deviceId`. This uid is constant on a per device per skill basis. That means it's different for different skills used by the same device. But it keeps being the same for one skill invoked from the same device.
You can use that data to partition your devices on skill level.

What I'd do in your specific situation is to auto-register a device in your DB with the first skill invocation from that device. Once it's registered you can manually edit the dataset and add a group, that this device is supposed to belong to.

Your skill backend (lambda) then checks, what group the device is in and delivers the according WIFI pw.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I really appreciate it. 

I've gone ahead in Alexa For Business console and created 3 separate room profiles, associated 3 Echos with those room profiles, then associated those room profile with separate, matching skill groups. So Echo 1 is associated with room 1 which is associated with skill group 1. If I'm understanding you correctly, all of the skill groups can still point to the same skill. Am I misunderstanding anything there?

Can you point to a sample of how to make my lambda check for the device's skill group.

Comment: Think of skill groups as a permission model. So you might have one group for everybody and one for the C-level guys of your company. In this scenario the two groups may share most of the skills. But the C group may have access to one or more additional skills, that offer sensitive information or powerful rights.

Comment: In your case I think one group for all devices is sufficient.

Comment: For coding, I highly recommend to use the official Node Alexa skills kit SDK: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs
That will make life way easier.

To get the deviceId in your sample code, try `event.context.System.device.deviceId` in the `exports.handler` function.